# APNS with Laravel Queues

Tags: laravel, push-notification, queue, apple-push-notifications

According to the APNS Documentation, Apple prefers that when you open up a connection, that you use that connection as much as possible before closing it. I am implementing custom push messages and dispatching them onto a queue. This means each worker will open up their own connection to APNS to send 1 push message.

The library I am using is: https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

Will I face any issues? Has anyone else implemented queuing with their push notifications in PHP/Laravel?